# Facebook publishing post, but receive error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I'm posting a message with a video with the publishing fb api:

```
$res = Http::post(env('FB_API').'31457605812596/videos?published=false&access_token='.'my-token', [
    'file_url' => 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/f4Cu9feSQuisHdTuncXz'
]);

$fileIds[] = ['media_fbid' => json_decode($res->body())->id];

$uri =
    env("FB_API") .
    '31457605812596' .
    "/feed?access_token=my-token";

$res = Http::post($uri, [
    "message" => 'Test',
    "attached_media" => $fileIds,
]);

dd($res->body());
```

It's published correctly and the video is there as well. But I receive back:

> {"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for
> this
> action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"AKAT6MW-1Z88JUnfH6PZdmP"}}

How is this even possible? Is this a bug at facebook side?

--EDIT

Permissions I have:

```
publish_to_groups 
pages_manage_engagement 
pages_read_user_content 
pages_read_engagement 
pages_manage_posts 
pages_show_list instagram_basic 
publish_video
```

I'm a admin for the selected page.

Comment: Ask Facebook - they will know about their errors.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I will. But I thought maybe I'm doing something obvious wrong. But I guess that's not the case.

Comment: Btw contacting fb seems impossible. I've posted to the community forum but not sure if that will work out :(

Comment: Which permissions does your access token include? Which tasks is the user who created it allowed to perform on the page?

Comment: Hi @Broe, thankyou for helping. I've updated my question with all permissions I have.